# Extracting strings from HTML with Python wont work with regex or BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im using Python 2.7, BeautifulSoup4, regex, and requests on windows 7.

I've scraped some code from a website and I am having problems parsing and extracting the bits I want and storing them in a dictionary. What I'm after is text that is presented as follows in the code:

```
@CAD_DTA\">I WANT THIS@G@H@CAD_LBL
```

there are about 50-60 short strings I want to extract and store and they are all preceded by `@CAD_DTA\">` and followed by `@G@H@CAD_LBL` in the code. These strings are all of variable length

I've tried:

```
re.search('@CAD_DTA\">(.+?)@G@H@CAD_LBL',result.text)
```

where `result` is the output of `s.post(url, data = cookie,  headers = {'referer': my_referer})`

Ive also tried passing `str(result.text)`

but `re.search` keeps returning `None`. It's odd because if I literally copy and paste the content of `result.text` into a string and pass that through `re.search` it works fine.

Ive tried using `re.search('@CAD_DTA">(.+?)@G@H@CAD_LBL',result.text)` in case the `\` is being treated as an escape or something. I dunno.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there a literal backslash before the double quote? `re.search(r'@CAD_DTA\\">(.+?)@G@H@CAD_LBL',result.text)` should work then.

Comment: That works! Thanks. I had tried the double backslash but without the 'r'. Anyway to reference the location that the string was found? So I can then go and search again starting at that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match the string with a literal backlash, you need to double-escape it in a raw string, e.g.:

```
re.search(r'@CAD_DTA\\">(.+?)@G@H@CAD_LBL',result.text)
          ^          ^
```

In order to get the index of the found match, you can use `start([group])`  of [re.MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/O91rZC):

```
import re
obj = re.search(r'@CAD_DTA\\">(.+?)@G@H@CAD_LBL', 'Some text here...@CAD_DTA\\">I WANT THIS@G@H@CAD_LBL')
print obj.start(1)
print obj.group(1)
```

Comment: I am also happy to help someone using appropriate tools for concrete tasks :)